# Is there a way to have two custom elements sharing a DOM element, e.g. an <iron-ajax>

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have two custom elements having similar functionality and both having an `<iron-ajax>` element(in local DOM template) to make service calls, I was trying to extract these common part into a behavior. But I also realize that polymer behavior does not carry local DOM template. Is there a way to let the behavior have the `<iron-ajax>`? dynamically create it using Document.create?

As "behavior" is the Polymer way of doing code sharing, can a DOM element be shared across elements?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an other element for your API calls which have inside the `<iron-ajax>` and have your api call methods, then you need just change the iron-ajax element in your elements and use your `<api-element>` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Below are two methods which i can think of

1. Create `iron-ajax` element at root level of your application and then refer to that element from each of your element using `querySelector` or `getElementById` on document
2. In your `behavior` create `iron-ajax` element from javascript with `createElement` function of javascript.

In both the cases you can add event listener on `response` and `error`.